# Question on number of solutions of $\sin (e^{x}) = e^{\sin x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $S_n$ be the number of solutions of 
$\sin (e^{x}) = e^{\sin x}$ in the interval $[0,2n\pi]$

Then find the value of 
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ S_n}{e^{2n\pi}}$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, please include your attempts and thoughts so we can adapt our answers to your needs.

Comment: @BillO'Haran i have edited the question..please check if possible

Comment: Please do add what you tried.

Comment: @AnkitSureka It's a good question but you should improve the way to ask that and show your work, try and doubts for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can show that

$$S_{n+1}-S_n\sim\frac{e^{2\pi n}(e^{2\pi}-1)}{\pi}$$

then note that by Stolz-Cesaro

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ S_n}{e^{2n\pi}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ S_{n+1}-S_n}{e^{2\pi(n+1)}-e^{2\pi n}}$$

Comment: I can see that $e^{sinx}$ lies in between [1/e,e] but that is not helping to find Sn

Comment: @AnkitSureka It seems we have only one solution that is for $x=0$.

Comment: Check in the graphical calculator,you can see there are many solutions.

Comment: @AnkitSureka Ah ok I was referring to $e^{\sin x} = e^x$, of course now it is different!